# Cables to meter box are too short

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, meter

I'm replacing a 45 year old meter box that the contacts had burnt up in. The service drop and main supply cables are too short to reach the new lugs. Can the main cables from the house be spliced inside the box in order to reach the lugs?

Comment: Can you find/buy a different (?bigger) meter box with lugs that work for you?   Or, can you move the meter box towards the service, so *that* reaches, and splice an extension to the supply cables in a new splice box? IDK if you can do it in the meter box but I know you can do it elsewhere. Just move the meter so is no need to splice both sides.

Comment: I believe splices are available for main cables, but they are on the expensive side.  Not sure of the price but 50 dollars a piece might be on the cheap side(I think they are closer to a 100$).

Answer (score 4):

Before you do anything, check with the power company to see if they'll provide you with a set of meter blocks, basically new guts but same can. You can also get them at electrical supply stores and possibly your home stores.

There are insulated splices for mains cables, $10 to $20 each, but you'd have to make sure they'll fit in your meter can with the bending radius of the cable and that the local authority and power company allows them.  You might be able to shorten up the drip loop if you have a weatherhead and get the line side to reach the lugs and then as a last resort, replace the cable from the load side of the meter to the main panel.